# ESLint rule to ensure JSX text nodes are not mixed with other nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

On my React application, I noticed multiple errors on production reported by Sentry. It was mostly: `NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`.
I discovered that these errors are actually caused by Google Translate that is messing with React DOM: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538

So now, if I want my React application to be more resilient to Google Translate and other plugins that changes the page DOM, I would like to ensure that text nodes are never mixed with other nodes. For that I am looking for an ESLint rule that would:

**Raise an error for this code**:

```
<div>
  {condition && 'Welcome'}
  <span>Something</span>
</div>
```

And instead, **accept the following code**:

```
<div>
  {condition && <span>Welcome</span>}
  <span>Something</span>
</div>
```

Is there already an ESLint rule that does that? If no, do you have any clue to build this rule?

Answer (score 0):

This project solves the problem:
https://github.com/sayari-analytics/eslint-plugin-sayari/tree/main

But it doesn't solve the problem when you have a variable with text in it:
e.g.

```
<div>
    {someString}
<SomethingElse />
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This ESLint rule may help you detect such cases: [eslint-plugin-jsx-expressions - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-expressions).